# Как ответвиться "от корня", чтобы работать над проектом B, несвязанным с проектом A в репозитории проекта A?

Tags: git, git-branch, github-pages

Хочу воспользоваться сервисом GitHub Pages, чтобы сделать сайт для своего репозитория. Почитав документацию вынес для себя, что наиболее удобный (по крайней мере лично для меня) способ размещения/работы над сайтом - это хранить его файлы в отдельной ветке `gh-pages`.

Проблема в том, что, откуда бы я не ответвился (`git branch gh-pages`), состояние этой новой ветки будет равно состоянию той ветки, от которой произошло ответвление. А, поскольку в ней (`gh-pages`) будет вестись работа *только* над сайтом, то иметь в ней все файлы самого проекта (да тем боле в том виде, в котором они были на момент ответвления) мне ни к чему.

Конечно, можно первым же коммитом эти ненужные в данном контексте файлы удалить. Но такое решение мне не особо по-душе, потому что:

1. Это лишняя работа
2. Это лишний коммит, который будет собой только засорять историю коммитов
3. Если в будущем случайно слить эту ветку куда-нибудь в другую (`master`, например), то этот коммит удалит необходимые для проекта файлы (если я правильно понимаю, конечно).

Идеальным для меня вариантом была бы возможность ответвиться не от какой-либо ветки, а от корня (от ствола, если хотите думать о репозитории как о дереве). Почему? Потому что работа над сайтом никак не связана с работой над самим проектом, из чего следует, что ветка должна получить свое "начальное состояние" из ничего (то есть быть изначально пустой на момент создания).

**Хотелось бы узнать**, как можно (и можно ли вообще) реализовать вышеизложенное? Или, может быть, для моих целей есть более рациональное решение? С удовольствием выслушаю, если так.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
git checkout --orphan gh_pages
git rm -rf .
```

> `--orphan <new_branch>`
>
> Создайте новую сиротскую ветвь, названную `<new_branch>`, начато с
>   `<start_point>` и переключитесь на него. Первый коммит сделанный в
>   этой новой ветке не будет иметь родителей и станет корнем новой
>   истории коммитов, полностью отключеной от всех других ветвей и
>   коммитов.

Далее нужно удалить все данные из рабочего каталога и индекса.

https://help.github.com/articles/creating-project-pages-using-the-command-line/

Comment: Прошу описать, что из этого зачем. И зачем здесь вообще `resret --hard`? Как-то меня смущает это...